# C++ change values defined in a class

Tags: c++, class, variables

I need to change some values defined in a class.

```
 class RandMT 
 {
   static const int N =          222; 
   static const int M =          100; 
   static const uint32 K =       0x9908B0DFU;
 }
```

In particular `N` and `M`.

If I change the type from `static const int` to `int`, I get this error:

> C:\Users\domi\Desktop\mersenne_twister.cpp|15|error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member `N'|

How can I do this?

Comment: You need C++11 support for that. Whether you can get that, and how, depends on the compiler. But the semantics are totally different. Do you really want to change the behaviour like that?

Comment: Why you removed the `static`? Replace `static const int N = 222;` with `static int N;` and add `int RandMT::N = 222;` AFTER class definition.